# MySQL the command line and pagers

Tags: mysql, linux, unix, command-line, pager

I cant find anything about this from searching here.

I use mysql on the command line at work and I work with fairly large tables so I set the mysql pager allowing a more readable result if I run a query, that returns 1000's of results. I use the command below to set the pager.

```
\P less -Sin
```

This suits my needs but has left me wondering if there are any more pager styles that mysql uses on the command line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The MySQL client just passes its output to whatever command you specify with `\P` (for "Pager").

`-Sin` are commandline switches to the program `less`. From [man less](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?less):

> -i Causes searches to ignore case
>   -n Suppresses line numbers
>   -S Causes lines longer than the screen width to be chopped rather than folded.

For more options of the [MySQL client, see reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-commands.html).

Comment: Note: use `\n` or `nopager` to turn off paging

Comment: TLDR: `\P` and `\n`

Comment: And alternatively: `pager less` and `pager stdout`

Answer (score 10):

```
mysql> pager less
PAGER set to 'less'
```

Comment: also if you just type `pager` it will go back to standard output.

Comment: Also, if you are using a very minimal OS that does not include ```less``` by default like I do on Docker, setting pager to ```more``` would be of far better than working with ```stdout```.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try [pspg](https://github.com/okbob/pspg): 
*Unix pager designed for work with tables. Designed for PostgreSQL, but MySQL is supported too*.

> Main target
>
> - possibility to freeze first few rows, first few columns
> - possibility to use fancy colors - like mcview or FoxPro

In action:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://www.percona.com/blog/2008/06/23/neat-tricks-for-the-mysql-command-line-pager/) is old, but still very helpful.

You can set the pager to whatever you want, including a script that parses all output before feeding it back to you. The examples there include using an add-on tool that makes `EXPLAIN` output more readable.

<sub>Also note that to turn off this functionality and return to normal stdout the command is `nopager`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like `less` you can use `more` :)

```
\P more
```

Comment: it's not that I don't like it, I'm just interested to see if more pager outputs exist. I just tried more and its very similar to the basic output. Using less seems to display the result set in a much neater fashion

Answer (score 0):

Use pager

```
mysql -u root --database=test
MariaDB[test]> pager less -SFX
DESCRIBE Alerts;
```

OUTPUT

```
    +----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id_alert             | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | id_importance_choice | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | score                | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | level                | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | users                | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | createdAt            | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | updatedAt            | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | deletedAt            | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Desable pager

```
MariaDB[test]> pager more
```